# Can I read an Excel file and keep the letters as colnames in R?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to read an .xlsx file.
I want to keep the column names in Excel (the ones that go from `A` to `Z` and then continues with `AA` `AB` etc) and use them as column names for my data.frame.

is there an easy way to import the excel and take them as headers?

The range is BR:CI (the rest I don't need)

### The code I use:

```
data = read.xlsx( # Reads only the relevant part of the data
  xlsxFile = "E:/data.xlsx",
  sheet = 1,
  colNames = F, 
  cols = c(70:87), #Cols BR-CI
  startRow = 2 )
```

### The output I get:

```
> head(data)
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16    X17    X18
1 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
2 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
3 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
4 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
5 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
6 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
```

### The output I want

```r
> head(data)
     BR    BS    BT    BU    BV    BW    BX    BY    BZ    CA    CB    CC    CD    CE    CF    CG     CH     CI
1 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
2 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
3 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
4 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
5 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
6 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 25569 204552 204552
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `openxlsx` package has the function `int2col()` to convert integers into Excel column indices.  You don't seem to be able to set the names as part of the import but you can do:

```
library(openxlsx)

data = read.xlsx( # Reads only the relevant part of the data
  xlsxFile = "E:/data.xlsx",
  sheet = 1,
  colNames = F, 
  cols = c(70:87), #Cols BR-CI
  startRow = 2 )

names(data) <- int2col(70:87)
```

Where `int2col(70:87)` gives:

```
 [1] "BR" "BS" "BT" "BU" "BV" "BW" "BX" "BY" "BZ" "CA" "CB" "CC" "CD" "CE" "CF" "CG" "CH" "CI"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
data = read.xlsx( # Reads only the relevant part of the data
  xlsxFile = "E:/data.xlsx",
  sheet = 1,
  colNames = F, 
  cols = c(70:87), #Cols BR-CI
  startRow = 2 )

names = read.xlsx(
 xlsxFile = "E:/data.xlsx",
 sheet = 1,
 colNames = T, #Changed this from your code to TRUE
 cols = c(70:87), #Cols BR-CI
 startRow = 1 ) ) # Change this from your code to start a row above

colnames(data) <- colnames(names)
```

Comment: No, it uses the descriptive column names I already have in the first line, which I don't need